# AsyncTask return null при повторном запросе

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

есть задача загрузить загрузить данные с api, обработать и передать список в mainActivity. Первый раз когда загружаю данные все работает отлично - при втором запуске asyncTask постоянно возвращает null. Поток срабатывает (в doinBackground генерирует новые данные, но не отправляет их в активити), как это исправить?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnStartSearch:
                String query_str = etSearch.getText().toString();
                if(!query_str.isEmpty()){
                    List<ContactItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    LoadAPI loadAPI = new LoadAPI();
                    loadAPI.execute(query_str);

                    list = loadAPI.get();

                    if(list == null){ Toast.makeText(this, "Введіть 
 коректніші дані пошуку!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                    else {
                        initRecycler(list);
                        Log.println(Log.INFO, "api", "list size - " + 
 list.size());
                    }

                    //loadAPI.cancel(true);
                    //loadAPI.execute("close", loadAPI.toString());
                    //loadAPI.execute();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Помилка! Введіть данні пошуку!", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                break;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

вот код потока

```
public class LoadAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<ContactItem>> {
private List<ContactItem> contactItemList;

@Override
protected List<ContactItem> doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        String query = URLEncoder.encode(strings[0], "UTF-8");
        String link_query = "https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/? 
q=" + query;

        Log.println(Log.INFO, "api", link_query);

        Document document = 
Jsoup.connect(link_query).ignoreContentType(true).get();
        String result = document.text();

        //dell
        Log.println(Log.INFO, "api", result);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray arrayTovars = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

        int count = jsonObject.getJSONObject("page").getInt("totalItems");

        if (count < 500) {
            contactItemList = new ArrayList<>();
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "api", "count: " + count);
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayTovars.length(); i++) {
                ContactItem contact = new ContactItem();

                JSONObject item = arrayTovars.getJSONObject(i);

                contact.setId(item.getString("id"));
                contact.setFirst_name(item.getString("firstname"));
                contact.setLast_name(item.getString("lastname"));
                contact.setMisce_rob(item.getString("placeOfWork"));
                contact.setPosada(item.getString("position"));
                contact.setLink_pdf(item.getString("linkPDF"));
                contact.setLink_pdf(item.getString("linkPDF"));

                contactItemList.add(contact);
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
        //String res = contactItemList.get(0).getLast_name() + " " + 
 contactItemList.get(0).getFirst_name();
        //Log.println(Log.INFO, "api", res);

        return contactItemList;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<ContactItem> list) {
    super.onPostExecute(list);

}
}
```

Спасибо огромное за помощь заранее

Comment: Может `count >= 500`?

Comment: да нет, там когда я ввожу данные заново возвращает 22, но все равно null в активити

Comment: Тогда исключения - ищите в логах `IOException` и `JSONException`

Comment: Ты был прав - была в логах было мол одно с полей пустое и из-за частого обращения туда возвращало почему-то null. Спасибо огромное!!:)